# Combine multiple conditionals using iterator

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering if there is a way in python and/or pandas to combine multiple conditionals using an interator. For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B': [1,2,3]})
df[(df.A == 1) & (df.B == 1)]
```

Now imagine the dataframe had columns A through Z, I would like to do something like:

```
df[and((df[column] == 1) for column in df.columns])]
```

to build that long (26 conditional) statement from a simple to construct iterator.

Comment: Your example would be: `df.eq(1).all(1)` (or similar - maybe `df.loc[:, 'A': 'Z'].eq(1).all(1)`)... but I imagine you're asking about more complicated queries?

Comment: Nope, you got it -- that works, thanks! Post that answer :)

Comment: Do you know of a way to do this in a regular if? for example
`if (my_dict['a'] = 1) and (my_dict['b'] = 1)`

Comment: Yeah... gimme a mo' that'll at least be an answer that's closer to what I thought you were answering

Comment: Or thinking about it... are you now not asking about pandas at all but wanted to check multiple values in a plain `dict`? Or did you want to use a dict of column name/values to filter a DF?

Comment: Was asking about doing similar thing outside of pandas entirely. Your first answer covers most of the use cases I can think of within pandas

Comment: @nven I think my answer works for that, depends on your data frame. Can you test for me?

Comment: Probably best to ask a new question with some examples with data that doesn't lean towards pandas solutions... something along the lines of: I have this and I want this, and for that I'd write... xyz... Your example of a `dict` there would be covered by other answers (if you can find 'em but I know I've seen 'em) showing how to compare a dict is a subset of another dict for instance

Answer (score 2):

You could construct a string that implement the request you need and then use it as query argument :

```
request='&'.join([' {}==1 '.format(c) for c in df.columns])
df.query(request)

    A   B
0   1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jon Clements posted the correct answer in a comment above

```
df[df.loc[:, 'A': 'Z'].eq(1).all(1)]
```

or

```
df[(df.loc[:, 'A': 'Z'] == 1).all(1)]
```

Comment: Didn't you ask to use an iterator ?

Comment: yes, (df.loc[:, 'A': 'Z'] == 1) returns an iterator, which is aggregated by .all(1)